# using subprocess to ssh and execute commands

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

I need to ssh into the server and execute few commands and process the response using subprocess. Here's my code

```
command = 'ssh -t -t buildMachine.X.lan; sudo su - buildbot ; build-set sets/set123'
print "submitting command"
result = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
print "got response"
response,err = result.communicate()
print response
```

This is getting stuck. I have seen other threads talking about passing a list instead of string to subprocess and removing shell=True.. I did that too but didn't work.

Ultimately I need the result of last command i.e. build-set in order to extract some information out of it.. help?

Comment: You need to pass the commands you want to execute remotely to `ssh` as the last argument, not as additional commands separated by `;`.

Comment: Do you have a passwordless login to the server?

Comment: @AshuPachauri yes - the private key is already stored in my machine so don't need to provide password again.

Comment: @univerio could you give an example?

Comment: @user2812714 You have to do `ssh host 'foo bar'` to run `foo bar` remotely. If you do `ssh host; foo bar` you're running `ssh host` locally, **waiting for `ssh` to exit**, then executing `foo bar` **locally**.

Comment: You really do want to split it up into a list and not use `shell=True`. It's hard enough to figure out how to split up `ssh` arguments vs. remote-host arguments without having to deal with an extra layer of quoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured the solution by using univerio's comment

The command needs to be

```
command = 'ssh -t -t buildMachine.X.lan \'sudo su - buildbot  \'build-set sets/set123\'\''
```

Individual commands are like argument to previous command. This works.